# using height, left, top, width to format a excel table in python

Tags: python, json, excel, xlwt

I met a weird JSON response and need to save it to a excel, I tried pandas but it doesn't work in the expected way(or maybe I'm using it incorrectly, I am new to python), now I'm trying to use `xlwt` to format it, but the only `params` I got in `JSON` response is "height, left, top, width":

e.g.:
`{'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 31, 'top': 22, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'A'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 301, 'top': 23, 'width': 14}, 'word': 'B'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 11, 'left': 698, 'top': 25, 'width': 11}, 'word': 'D'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 10, 'left': 829, 'top': 25, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'E'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 11, 'left': 909, 'top': 23, 'width': 14}, 'word': 'F'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 993, 'top': 24, 'width': 13}, 'word': 'G'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 1076, 'top': 24, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'H'}`..............and many more lines

I cannot just iterate through it because it will not start a new row if I do so.

Please kindly tell me how I could utilize the "height, left, top, width".

Answer (score 0):

This is a plain json response, but it is a nested response, which makes it difficult to load into pandas directly. In the solution below I assume that you have [loaded the json response](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) as a python list of dictionaries called 'data'.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 31, 'top': 22, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'A'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 301, 'top': 23, 'width': 14}, 'word': 'B'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 11, 'left': 698, 'top': 25, 'width': 11}, 'word': 'D'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 10, 'left': 829, 'top': 25, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'E'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 11, 'left': 909, 'top': 23, 'width': 14}, 'word': 'F'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 993, 'top': 24, 'width': 13}, 'word': 'G'}, {'rect': {'angle': -90, 'height': 12, 'left': 1076, 'top': 24, 'width': 12}, 'word': 'H'}]

#assuming you wish to include the word variable in a column as well, let's add it to the 'rect' key so we can load the rect keys into a pandas dataframe
for i in data:
  i['rect']['word'] = i['word']

#we need to create a list that only contains the data from the rect keys, otherwise pandas can't load it. So let's use list comprehension
df=pd.DataFrame([i['rect'] for i in data])
df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

output:

```
    angle   height  left    top width   word
0   -90     12      31      22  12      A
1   -90     12      301     23  14      B
2   -90     11      698     25  11      D
3   -90     10      829     25  12      E
4   -90     11      909     23  14      F
```